# Changing the name when submitting to the app store

Tags: app-store, apple-id

I am working on an app but being under 18, I am not allowed to have my own Developer account so I used my parent's. I don't want the submitted app to be under their names so is there any way to not list the name on the apple ID when submitting to the app store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope you can't do that. Not only do you need to submit the app under their name you'll also have to sell the app under their name (meaning in the app store their name will appear after the "by ..."). 
When you turn 18 you can create your own developer account and transfer all your assets.

Comment: I see some apps have company names under them. Can I do that?

Comment: Only if your company is properly registered.